# Restore an Android sqlite database from one device to another device

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to copy a sqlite database file that resides on the root of the SD Card from one device to another device running my application.

I need to do this, because I need to debug the application with the database from one of our customer's device, witch is presenting a bug.

Our customer sent us the database file (copied by USB connection).

The file opens with no problem using a desktop client, but when I try to run the application in my device, the following exception occurs:

> 08-07 19:15:17.707:
>   E/br.com.logann.rotasmovel.application.RotasApplication(1799): Caused
>   by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database
>   disk image is malformed

Does any one know how to do this? How to copy the file from one device to another without corrupting the database?

Comment: How the client can get the LIVE database from a device? Did you have a mechanism to export database to the sdcard, or is device rooted?

Comment: @Maxim The application saves the database file directly on the root of the SDCard (instead of the private application memory). Our client just connected the device (a Xoom) into the USB and copied the database file.

Comment: if client can open and read db and copy of it is corrupted when attempting to load on another device, then I can assume that db copying mechanism is probably broken. No more ideas, sorry.